AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' to retrieve data table
I want to scrap the data table from the web, and there is an error occurred in for looping statement
below is my code
table_body = soup.find("tbody")
rows = []

for row in table_body.find_all("tr"):
    cols = row.find_all("td")
    rd = cols[0].text.strip()
    mv = cols[1].text.strip()
    pb = cols[2].text.strip()
    dg = cols[3].text.strip()
    wg = cols[4].text.strip()
        
    rows.append([rd, mv, pb, dg, wg])

headers = ["Release Date", "Movie", "Production Budget", "Domestic Gross", "Worldwide Gross"]

and this message error when I have tried running a code
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 4
      1 table_body = soup.find("tbody")
      2 rows = []
----> 4 for row in table_body.find_all("tr"):
      5     cols = row.find_all("td")
      6     rd = cols[0].text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

what should I do?

it means there are no <tr> tags. Can you share the url and I can take a look?

sure, this is the url: https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all

Is table_body null?  If Beautiful Soup is scraping the HTML not the DOM, there is no tbody element, just at table with tr children.  Note that the first tr element has th not td children...

In the html source, there is no <tbody> tag. So that returns None, which then inevitably will return no <tr> tags.
change table_body = soup.find("tbody") to table_body = soup.find("table")
Or, even an easier solution, let pandas parse the table:
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

df = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]

Output:
print(df)
    Unnamed: 0  Release Date  ... Domestic Gross Worldwide Gross
0            1  Dec 16, 2015  ...   $936,662,225  $2,064,615,817
1            2   Dec 9, 2022  ...   $684,075,767  $2,317,514,386
2            3  Jun 28, 2023  ...   $174,480,468    $383,963,057
3            4  Apr 23, 2019  ...   $858,373,000  $2,748,242,781
4            5  May 20, 2011  ...   $241,071,802  $1,045,713,802
..         ...           ...  ...            ...             ...
95          96  Feb 28, 2020  ...    $61,555,145    $133,357,601
96          97  Nov 22, 2023  ...    $61,524,375    $217,917,156
97          98  Dec 16, 2020  ...    $46,801,036    $166,360,232
98          99  Jan 31, 2024  ...    $45,207,275     $96,210,855
99         100   Sep 4, 2020  ...             $0     $69,973,540

[100 rows x 6 columns]


Sorry, I'm new to web scraping and I don't understand what value the headers variable in the second solution contains. How can I create this?

its the header for the get request. When you go to the page in the browser, you can Inspect the page (ctrl-shft-i) - you might need to refresh, but in the Network tab, you should see the request come in, and then can see what is in the header for the get request

Also did the solution work?

The second solution worked, but the first did not. Thanks for your explanation, maybe for the next i will read and learn more. Have a good day!

Then kindly accept the solution. Also, it's possible that first one does actually work. Are you using the headers to do the request before using beatufulsoup there?

Sorry, I forgot to accept it. Yes, I did, but a new error emerged afterward: 'IndexError: list index out of range

if you edit and share the full code, I could help you debug that error.

Thank you for the offer, i really appreciate it. However, i think the second solution would be easier for me as a newbie
